# Matplotlib Plot with date time

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, data-visualization

I visualzie data with matplotlib in python, data is stock price history (data day by day) and this data have date time, i want to create a plot with date time is x axis (but only show year on x axis, because it is not space enough to show all).

My dataset is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1KKXxdIthSRG9aN6QJBetyy1i5_Kjie/view?usp=sharing

My code is

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Stock Price History')
plt.plot(df['Close'])
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Stock Price', fontsize = 18)
plt.show()
```

but result in x axis is index of line data, can you help me fix it, i really thank you!!
[image]

Comment: have you tried to reset the index? or call the x also in the plt.plot-function in stead of only the y. --> plt.plot(df['date'], df['close'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set xticks for your plot. This sets it for every 250th data point.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Stock Price History')
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Close'])
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Stock Price', fontsize = 18)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::250])
plt.show()
```

[image]